# SAS set missing value to 0 with array, while columns contain mixed data types

Tags: sas

I am reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877719/5705174) about setting all missing values of a dataset to 0.

However, it seems that it only apply to datasets with numeric data types only. What if I have data with character and numeric data types at the same time? I cannot declare an array like `array a(*) _numeric_;` or `array a(*) _character_;`, and it seems that using *ALL* is not acceptable in arrays. What is the appropriate ways to get around it then?

Comment: You state you cannot use the _numeric_ or _character_ lists but then marked that response as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want BOTH numeric and character variables to be set to 0 / "0" you have to run two arrays - eg as follows:

```
array __missnums _numeric_;
do over __missnums;
  if __missnums=. then __missnums=0;
end;
array __misschars _character_;
do over __misschars;
  if __misschars="" then __misschars="0";
end;
```

It makes no difference if your dataset contains variables of both types, the `_numeric_` and `_character_` keywords only apply to the numeric / character vars accordingly.